# Getting RESOLUTION_REQUIRED always even if user press the 'OK" button in the case of checking location settings

Tags: android, android-gps, google-location-services

My LocationRequest is set to PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY. But in xiaomi redmi note 5 device if i press the ok button in the location settings dialog it always returns 0 through onActivityResult() method and i get "com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException: 6: RESOLUTION_REQUIRED". But i have tested in some other devices it works fine. I have used this gps enabled/not enabled checking inside a fragment.

```
/////Code that prompts up the dialog

SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getActivity ());
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        task.addOnSuccessListener(getActivity (), new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
                // location requests here.
                // ...
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(getActivity (), new OnFailureListener () {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                  if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(getActivity (),
                                REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                }
            }
        });

/////// onActivityResult() method inside my fragment
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        try {
            super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (resultCode) {
                case -1:
                    requestLocationUpdates ();

                    break;
                case 0:
                   displayLocationSettingsRequest (getContext ());
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }


    }
```

Comment: did anybody found the solution?

Comment: I resolved this by https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient

Answer (score 1):

I found some link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331118

Check your location request object.
When I'm using,

```
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

it's repeatedly fires `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException: 6: RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` exception.

When I changed to,

```
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

it's working fine.

Please give a try and post your updates.

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution is to turn Google Location Accuracy ON from location settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).