# SettingsClient.checkSettings always fails with status LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, android-location

I am using `LocationServices` in my application. Before using location services I am trying to verify if Location with required settings is ON but the problem I am facing is that `SettingsClient.checkSettings` always `failing`. Please see my `LocationRequest` and `LocationSettingRequest` builder:

**LocationRequest**

```
 mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.interval = interval
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = interval

        Log.v(TAG, "distance => $distance")
        if(distance > 0) {
            mLocationRequest.smallestDisplacement = distance
        }

        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        buildLocationSettingsRequest()
```

**LocationSettingRequestBuilder**

```
private fun buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build()

        mSettingsClientInit = true
    }
```

And I am requesting `checkSettings` as

```
mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, object : OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse> {

                    override fun onSuccess(locationSettingsResponse: LocationSettingsResponse) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "LocationManager: All location settings are satisfied.");
                        mLocationCallback?.let {
                            fusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                        }
//                        updateUI();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, object : OnFailureListener {
                    override fun onFailure(e: Exception) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Request PErmission failure");
                        var statusCode = (e as ApiException).getStatusCode()
                        when (statusCode) {
                            LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> {
                                try {
                                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                    // result in onActivityResult().
                                    var rae = e as ResolvableApiException;
                                    rae.startResolutionForResult(this@BaseLocationActivity, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                } catch (sie: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                                    Log.v(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                                }
                            }
                            LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                                mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                                Log.v(TAG, "Settings change unavailable.");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                )
```

It is always resulting `onFailure` of `addOnFailureListener`. Can anyone please help me what can be the issue? This settings dialog shows OK to enable settings, I press OK, again same dialog appears with onFailure callback.

> It is occuring on some devices, not on all devices.

Comment: Did you try with a different priority than `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331118/2668136))?

Comment: No, Even the device is in High accuracy mode that is Enable providers are Network and GPS , still this checkLocationSettings returns failure

Comment: @Mustansar Saeed refer dis ``` https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311891/12273964 ```

Answer (score 2):

Hello follow this code to resolve your problem, I added GPSUtils class with the help of this class you can easily manage GPS.

**GpsUtils.Class**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
public class GpsUtils {
private Context context;
    private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
public GpsUtils(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context);
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
//**************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
        //**************************
    }
// method for turn on GPS
    public void turnGPSOn(onGpsListener onGpsListener) {
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if (onGpsListener != null) {
                onGpsListener.gpsStatus(true);
            }
        } else {
            mSettingsClient
                    .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                    .addOnSuccessListener((Activity) context, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
//  GPS is already enable, callback GPS status through listener
                            if (onGpsListener != null) {
                                onGpsListener.gpsStatus(true);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener((Activity) context, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                            switch (statusCode) {
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
try {
                                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                        // result in onActivityResult().
                                        ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                        rae.startResolutionForResult((Activity) context, AppConstants.GPS_REQUEST);
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                    String errorMessage = "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " +
                                            "fixed here. Fix in Settings.";
                                    Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
Toast.makeText((Activity) context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
public interface onGpsListener {
        void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable);
    }
}
```

GPS Dialog will be shown for SettingsClient’s failure callback and it will result in an activity’s onActivityResult(). So basically if the user agrees for turn on GPS, we can enable GPS flag in our activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == AppConstants.GPS_REQUEST) {
            isGPS = true; // flag maintain before get location
        }
    }
}
```

and now call GpsUtils class before getting a location.

```
new GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn(new GpsUtils.onGpsListener() {
    @Override
    public void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable) {
        // turn on GPS
        isGPS = isGPSEnable;
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is even If all conditions for success listener is  satisfied still in some devices onError is Occurring and it is not always,,

Answer (score 0):

After doing a good amount of research I got a solution for this ...

The problem is basically if the `LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED == true` then the next consecutive call you make will always result in the same output

i.e if you are calling this function recursively you will get RESOLUTION_REQUIRED always recursively so avoid calling this function recursively

**How You Might be calling it recursively?**

You might be getting the result_code of the resolution result and if its `RESULT_OK` you might be calling the same function to set up the location

for more info check my answer here for another similar question [Android LocationServices.checkLocationSettings false negative result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649666/android-locationservices-checklocationsettings-false-negative-result)