# Android LocationServices.checkLocationSettings false negative result

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

**Affected devices so far:**

- Xperia 1 II
- Xiamoi Redmi Note 7

**Use:**
In order to request location updates, I check that the location settings
are adequate beforehand. If not, I show a small text, that the services must
be enabled for my feature. If the user clicks on it, the system dialog to enable
the location service will be prompted.

**How I run the check:**
I run the check through `LocationSettingsRequest` and `LocationServices` and
handle the `ResolvableApiException`. If the Service is disabled by the user,
then on all my devices this will show the System Dialog, asking the user to enable
the service (and enables it, if okay is clicked).

**What happens instead on Redmi:**
But for whatever reason, on Xiamoi Redmi Note 7, the `checkLocationSettings`
will **always** return with an `ResolvableApiException`, even if the service
is already enabled. The Dialog **won't** appear and directly return a positive result
(sure, because the service is enabled).
Hence, the user is stuck and clicks forever on "enable".

Does somebody has any information why the `LocationSettingsRequest` is not working
properly on those devices and knows how to fix it?

**Example Code snippet**

```
void enableLocationSettings(onLocationServiceRequiredCallback: ICallback) {
   LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
         .setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
         .setExpirationDuration(LOCATION_UPDATE_EXPIRATION_DURATION)
         .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

    LocationServices
            .getSettingsClient(this)
            .checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, (LocationSettingsResponse response) -> {
                // update location as usual
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, error -> {
                if (error instanceOf ApiException) {
                    int statusCode = error.statusCode;
                    if(statusCode == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED) {
                        if(error instanceOf ResolvableApiException) {
                            PendingIntent resolution = error.resolution 
             // This will trigger the system dialog, see below
                            onLocationServiceRequiredCallback(resolution);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // error callback
            });
```

Unfortunately the code for the callback will now be kotlin. Sorry for that. I can only post "example code snippets", since this is work related.

It uses `ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult` to start
the system dialog.

`resolution` is the PendingIntent from above.

The contract:

```
private val locationServiceContract = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
) { activityResult ->
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        val result = if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // This will retrigger the location fetch (looping)
            enableLocationSettings(...) 
        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

After the callback from above is called, this will get executed:

```kotlin
        locationServiceContract.launch(
            IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                resolution
            ).build()
        )
```

Dump of `LocationSettingsStates`, aquired using the deprecated LocationSettings API (which is using GoogleApiClient):

```
isGpsPresent: true, 
isGpsUsable: false, 
isLocationPresent: true, 
isLocationUsable: true, 
isNetworkLocationPresent: true, 
isNetworkLocationUsable: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I use different code in order to check if GPS is enabled on a device. maybe its worth for you to try it out and see if it resolves your issue.

```
 private boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(locationManager);
    }
```

I then send the user to settings through a dialog using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

I bet you are doing the same. After sending the user to enable GPS you can just run the method a second time on resume

let me know if this helps

Comment: Thank you! I know this approach, too. But unfortunately this involves the user to manually enable the settings, while in contrast using the ResolvableApiException can be used to open a system dialog, which will (if the user allows it) to directly enable location services. I really want to know why my worflow (which is also advertised by google itself) fails here.

Comment: i understand. could you maybe log the resolvableApiException for your redmi and post it

Comment: could you also share the code where you cacthc the result of the user interaction. I still dont get wy it would eternally loop on the enable dialog

Comment: I updated the question. Unfortunately I can not 100% copy my work related code. But the snippet is hopefully enough to understand what is happening. 

I also updated the example code for the fetch. The PendingIntent will be inside the ResolvableApiException, for error statusCode RESOLUTION_REQUIRED (code 6).

Comment: I also noticed the same happens with Xperia 1 II device.

Comment: ok so I guess I have a hunch on what is happening. let me know if I am completely lost but you seem to be calling your location permissions code everytime your activity resumes and upon a renewed check everytime the onFailureListener callback is triggered. Endlessly showing you the same dialog. My best guess is that those devices are somehow failing  to fulfill the specifics in your locationRequest and that is why they always trigger a failure

Comment: my suggestion is that you try to log the result of  `LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build())` for those devices and see if you can find aspects of it that dont match up with your requirements (particularly explore LocationSttingsStates and LocationSettingsStatusCodes) https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsResult

Comment: a hailmary that might be worth a shot is calling `checkLocationSettings(fusedLocProviderClient,builder.build())` instead of just `checkLocationSettings(builder.build())` as per the official documentation

Comment: .... and just in order to get it out of my system I think permission-wise it might be overkill to check for the specifics of your `locationRequest`.  in my app I simply prompt the user to enable location using checkPermissions and the code in my answer, all aditional details such as update interval and expiration are dealt with automatically. I say it cause this might be the cause of the issue

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check this right now (remote). But I will hopefully this week and come back to you. "let me know if I am completely lost[...]", no you're not. That is how it is done right now. Since the suggestion to log the location state in detail, which might not fit the super detailed requirement from LocationRequest  might be a good hint, I'll accept that, in terms of the bounty, before it expires.

Comment: May I ask, in which official documentation you found that checkLocationSettings can be called with ProviderClient? `LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(fusedLocProviderClient, builder.build())` ?

Comment: > it might be overkill to check for the specifics of your locationRequest[...] 
Do you mean to not add the specifics at all for a `LocationRequest` and `requestLocationUpdates`, or just not within `LocationSettingsRequest` request?

Comment: here you see the documentation you asked for https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi#public-abstract-pendingresultlocationsettingsresult-checklocationsettings-googleapiclient-client,-locationsettingsrequest-locationsettingsrequest. Upon closer inspection fuselLocationproviderClient does not extend GoogleApiClient  but maye you can get it alternatively

Comment: and yes, maybe try to remove the details in your locationRequest gradually and see if eventually the issue disappears on your redmi7

Comment: This is the deprecated API, which I am not using :) `LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(..)` does not allow provider nor apiClient as argument.
But for testing purposes it might be worth to check the result of the deprecated api.

Comment: For further readers and to sum this up. Using the deprecated API is not an option. I used it for testing purposes anyway, to gain insights. It gives the same result as the current API. Meaning the statusCode is still `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED`, even if the LocationRequest has no configuration at all. So the old api did not give me any new insights, which I did not already know - unfortunately. I'll post a dump of LocationSettingsState at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a good amount of research I got a solution for this ...

The problem is basically, if the `LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED == true` then the next consecutive call you make will always result in the same output

i.e if you are calling this function recursively you will get RESOLUTION_REQUIRED always so what you can do is modify your contract to something like this

```
private val locationServiceContract = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
) { activityResult ->
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        val result = if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Dont call this as it will retrigger the location fetch (looping)
           // enableLocationSettings(...) 
               requestForLocationUpdates() // create this method see method body below
              
        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

**requestForLocationUpdates()**

```
 private fun requestForLocationUpdates() {

          locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
               override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                    if (locationResult.locations.size > 0) {
                          // update location as usual using locationResult.locations[0] or other item
                         fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
                    }
               }
          }

          fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
               locationRequest,
               locationCallback,
               Looper.getMainLooper()
          )
     }
```